# How to organize projects in TFS?

Tags: tfs, agile

We have 2 developers that are working on 8 applications. Should I split them in separate projects or keep all in one project? If i should split them, than how can I work with aggregated agile board? Keeping separate agile boards is not very useful because since there will be much more agile boards then developers.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to keep TFS projects for a group of related applications.  For example, if you have a website, an app, a webservice, and a scheduled task all working on essentially the same data but for different scenarios, I would group those as a single TFS project.

However, if two applications are fundamentally different they should be segregated from each other.  For example, one is a mobile eCommerce application, another is a video game about elephants fighting zombies armed only with a canoe paddle.

That way, the task board makes sense from a logical perspective.  With related applications, you'll have stories that cut across all of the projects.  You may have a common data layer service, or perhaps they all use a common engine that you want to be able to maintain on the same cadence.